# Как вызвать метод у уже готового экземпляра класса, без создания нового?

Tags: python, многопоточность

Я создаю помодоро приложение с помощью паттерна State

У меня есть таймер, созданный с помощью eventloop. Он вызывает функцию каждую секунду. в этой функции я отнимаю -1 от переменной remainingSeconds. Перед запуском таймера я объявляю переменную remainingSeconds c значением по умолчанию = 0, А после передаю ей значение workTimeInterval контекста класса Pomodoro = 10. После вызова таймера (self.timer.resume()) и запуска eventloop все происходит как я и ожидаю, функция вызываеться через 1 секунду. НО значение remaining seconds возвращается к своему дефолтному значению = 0, хотя я поменял его на 10. И из-за этого вызывается assert который я поставил.

**ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЯ С ДЕБАГГЕРА ПРИЛАГАЮТСЯ**

```
class Pomodoro:

    workTimeInterval = 10
    _state = None

    def __init__(self, workTimeInterval, breakTimeInterval, restTimeInterval, numberOfCycles):
        self.workTimeInterval = workTimeInterval
        self._state = StateNeutral()
        self._state.context = self

class BaseState:

    def __init__(self):
        self._pomodoro = None

    @property
    def context(self):
         return self._pomodoro

    @context.setter
    def context(self, pomodoro):
        self._pomodoro = pomodoro

    def didEnter(self):
        pass

class PomodoroTimer:

    def __init__(self, eventLoop, callback):
        self._eventLoop = eventLoop
        self._callback = callback
        self._fireTime = None

    def suspend(self):
        if self._fireTime is not None:
            self._fireTime = None

    def resume(self):
        if self._fireTime is None:
            self._fireTime = self._eventLoop.time() + 1.0
            self._eventLoop.call_at(self._fireTime, self.onTimer)

    def onTimer(self):
        self._callback()
        if self._fireTime is not None:
            self._fireTime += 1.0
            self._eventLoop.call_at(self._fireTime, self.onTimer)

class StateActive(BaseState):

    eventLoop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    timer = PomodoroTimer(eventLoop, lambda: StateActive().timerDidFire())

    _substate = Substate.working
    remainingSeconds = 0

    def didEnter(self):
        assert self._substate == Substate.working
        self.remainingSeconds = self.context.workTimeInterval
        self.timer.resume()
        self.eventLoop.run_forever()

    def timerDidFire(self):
        # call assert because variable remainingSeconds is 0 again
        assert self.remainingSeconds > 0
        self.remainingSeconds -= 1
        print(self.remainingSeconds)
        if self.remainingSeconds > 0:
            self.continueSubstate()
        else:
            self.switchToNextSubstate()
```

[image: debug1]

[image: debug2]

[image: debug3]

[image: debug4]

[image: debug5]

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понимаю, где у вас вообще вызывается `didEnter`. Но суть видимо в другом. Если вы внимательно посмотрите на скриншоты, то увидите, что в конце у вас `StateActive` уже с другим `id` ("... object at ..."). Видимо, из-за этого кода:

```
timer = PomodoroTimer(eventLoop, lambda: StateActive().timerDidFire())
```

Тут вы в лябмде **создаёте новый объект** `StateActive` и тут же вызываете у него метод `timerDidFire`. Для нового объекта `self.remainingSeconds` копируется из поля `remainingSeconds` класса, а там у вас `0`.

Вам нужно разобраться во-первых когда вызывается `didEnter`, а во-вторых хотите вы вызывать `timerDidFire` от нового объекта или всё же от готового экземпляра класса `StateActive`, в котором вы этот `PomodoroTimer` создаёте. Тогда это было бы так, наверное:

```
timer = PomodoroTimer(eventLoop, lambda: self.timerDidFire())
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ! Код я выложил не весь, остальное оставил потому что как мне показалось проблема только в этой части. Проблема действительно в том, что вы написали, и мне нужно вызывать `timerDidFire` у уже готового экземпляра. Я сменил на то, что вы написали, но мне выдает ошибку "Unresolved reference 'self' ". Я попробовал добавить аргумент 'self' к лямбде `timer = PomodoroTimer(eventLoop, lambda self: self.timerDidFire())` и теперь оно выдает ошибку "TypeError: StateActive.<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". Может, знаете в чем проблема?

Comment: Вот полная версия - http://dpaste.org/92Qq

Comment: Ой, что-то я не до конца сообразил, тогда вам это дело надо в `__init__(self):` перенести что ли (который нужно создать), сейчас этот код выполняется от класса, а не от экземпляра. Но я не уверен. Тут нужно сообразить всё-таки что и в каком порядке вы хотите чтобы выполнялось. Я позже попробую полный код глянуть.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен, если глянете!

Comment: @EugeneMaltsev Что-то я так сходу не могу за вас логику продумать. Там надо разбираться что откуда создаётся, у вас связь объектов не вертикальная, а какая-то сложная, нет понятной иерархии. Там нужно переписывать иерархию объектов, чтобы нормально всё было.